# Adjectif possessif « leur »

Tags: adjectifs, accord, possessif, homophone

Je me demande comment écrire et interpréter « leur » en tant qu’adjectif possessif (pour le pronom, c’est simple).

> Ex.: Les élèves ont laissé leur **sac** sur le sol.

Ici, on veut dire qu’un seul sac appartient à tous les élèves. C’est simple, si une chose appartient à un groupe, leur+le nom qui l’accompagne est au singulier.

> Ex.: Ils ont vendu leur maison.

Autrement dit, une seule maison pour ceux qui y habitent.

Sauf que, si on parle d’une classe d’élèves qui ont tous laissé leur sac individuel sur le sol, comment devrais-je l’écrire ? Doit-on considérer que :

a. Chaque élève à son propre sac (un seul sac), donc écrire:

> *Les élèves ont laissé leur **sac** sur le sol.*

Mais dans ce cas, comment distinguer si la phrase veut dire: un sac pour tout le groupe comme je l’ai cité dans mon premier exemple? Les deux phrases sont identiques.

Ou dois-je l’interpréter comme: Plusieurs élèves ont laissé un sac, donc au total, il y a plusieurs sacs donc:

> Les élèves ont laissé leurs **sacs** sur le sol.

Mais… admettons que chaque élève a plusieurs sacs, on doit forcément écrire :

> Les élèves ont laissé leurs **sacs** sur le sol.

Bref, à mon sens,

> *Les élèves ont laissé leur **sac** sur le sol.*

Deux sens possibles:

1. Un sac pour le groupe.
2. Chaque élève a son sac.

> *Les élèves ont laissé leurs **sacs** sur le sol.*

Deux sens possible:

3. Chaque élève a plusieurs sacs.
4. Chaque élève a son sac.

Dans tous les cas, 2 & 4 sont écrites différemment mais on le même sens.

Comment départager le sens de chaque phrase ? Je ne m’y retrouve plus !

Comment: Il y a effectivement ambiguïté et tout ce qu'on peut répondre c'est qu'il faut utiliser le contexte et son bon sens au cas par cas. Pour répondre à l'edit : la véritable question n'est pas sur le *leur*/*leurs* - car on se pose la même question sur nos/notre/ vos/votre, etc. (« Posez-vos sacs par terre ! » Chacun a-t-il un ou plusieurs sacs, hors contexte on ne le sait pas). C'est sur cette notion ambiguïté que porte la question liée.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que cette question soit vraiment un doublon et j'ai voté pour réouvrir.

Comment: @LukeSawczak merci de ne pas répondre en commentaire. C'est contraire aux bonnes pratiques de ce site.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Je n'ai pas répondu mais commenté. Une fois la question rouverte, une réponse serait possible et bien souhaitable à la place d'un commentaire.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Après y avoir réfléchi, la question me paraît assez distincte pour qu'on tente d'y répondre vu que l'auteur comprend ce que ça implique de faire l'accord au singulier ou au pluriel — ce dont on parle dans l'autre fil — mais semble plutôt vouloir distinguer d'entre plusieurs implications ambiguës (autrement que par les tournures déjà proposées dans la question ? je ne vois pas la logique). Je supprime mon commentaire et laisse le champ aux autres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bref, à mon sens,
>
> ```
> Les élèves ont laissé leur sac sur le sol.
> ```
>
> Deux sens possibles:
>
> ```
> Un sac pour le groupe.
> Chaque élève a son sac.
> ```

> ```
> Les élèves ont laissé leurs sacs sur le sol.
> ```
>
> Deux sens possible:
>
> ```
> Chaque élève a plusieurs sacs.
> Chaque élève a son sac.
> ```

Oui, c'est juste, et il n'y a aucun autre moyen de lever l'ambiguïté que regarder le contexte. En général c'est suffisant.

La règle est bien résumée [ici](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regle-orthographe/leur-chapeau-leurs-chapeaux-adjectif-possessif-singulier-pluriel-accord/):

> En bref
>
> – une chose pour plusieurs possesseurs = singulier
>
> – plusieurs choses pour chaque possesseur = pluriel
>
> – une chose pour chaque possesseur = singulier ou pluriel

PS : la même chose existe [en anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33383/330541), dans une moindre mesure.

Comment: Merci! Ça confirme ce que je pensais et je suis rassuré que la question ait été réouverte, je ne comprenais pas cette histoire de doublon.

Answer (score -3):

Dans l'usage, on écrit "leurs sacs" au pluriel quand il y a plusieurs sacs en tout, même si chaque élève en a un seul. Pour s'en convaincre on peut essayer de tourner la phrase avec une autre personne ("nous", pour à la fois éviter l'homophonie et l'ambiguité du vouvoiement), dans un cas où les deux sens seraient aussi probables:

> Nous, les manifestants, nous avons défilé pour faire valoir nos revendications.

> Nous, les manifestants, nous avons défilé pour faire valoir notre revendication.

On sent bien que le second cas suppose une revendication commune, partagée par tous les manifestants, alors que le premier pourrait aussi bien suggérer que chaque manifestant est venu avec sa propre revendication (voire ses revendications), ou qu'il y a plusieurs revendications mais qui sont toutes partagées par tous les manifestants.

Maintenant, si on voulait expliciter que chaque manifestant est venu avec sa propre revendication, on peut utiliser plutôt une formulation avec "chaque", ou "chacun":

> Nous, les manifestants, nous avons défilé pour que chacun puisse faire valoir sa revendication.

> Chaque élève a laissé tomber son sac sur le sol.

Dans ce cas "sac" et "revendication" sont bien au singulier car on se place à l'échelle de l'individu.

Comment: "Ils ont laissé leur sac" peut aussi désigner chaque sac pris individuellement, sans avoir recours à une périphrase : https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regle-orthographe/leur-chapeau-leurs-chapeaux-adjectif-possessif-singulier-pluriel-accord/

Comment: @guillaume31 C'est sûrement vrai pour l'Académie mais ce n'est pas l'usage en cours par les locuteurs contemporains, en tous cas certainement pas quand il y a risque d'ambiguité.

Comment: Je ne vois pas pourquoi... Et c'est aussi valable pour "nous" : *Enfants, après avoir laissé notre sac au vestiaire, nous courions vers le terrain de sport*

Comment: @guillaume31 Vous n'entendriez jamais cette phrase dans la bouche d'un locuteur contemporain.

Comment: Ah, je ne dois pas être un locuteur contemporain alors, ni [ces auteurs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ont%20laiss%C3%A9%20leur%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_fr) d'ailleurs : 
_"Des complices à qui elles ont laissé **leur** carte d'identité avant de quitter la France"_ (2018, un exemple parmi des centaines)